# Custom directory that is under `app` is missing in production `autoload_paths`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've setup `sidekiq` for my application. I am placing my workers in a newly created subdirectory `app/workers/`. Presumably, rails is expected to autoload any subdirectories under `app/`. If I evaluate

```
puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
```

in a rails console, in development, it *does* include

```
".../app/workers"
```

In production however, the new directory is missing. Other custom folders I've placed under `app/`, namely `services/` and `validators/`, do show up in the autoload_paths for both production and development.

I've seen answers to other questions that suggest restarting spring, however, this is happening in production for me.

`services/` and `validators/` existed the first time I deployed my app to production (using Capistrano), while `workers/` is from a subsequent commit.

Comment: Pls show the `initiallizers/sidekiq.rb` file and `environment/production.rb` vs `environment/development.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

My unicorn deploy script included `bin/` in the `linked_dirs`. Rails console is booted from `bin` so it needs to represent the current release. I removed `bin/` from `shared_dirs`